# MGF Of a Normal-Gamma Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

According to wikipedia, the normal-gamma distribution is actually, unconditionally, a nonstandardized t-distribution. The MGF of t-distributions do not exist. However, I can make the following argument to calculate the MGF of a normal-gamma, where does this fail?
Suppose X|$\sigma^2$~Normal(0,$\sigma^2$) and $\sigma^2$~Gamma(a,b).

$E(e^{tX})=E(E(e^{tX}|\sigma^2))=E(e^{\mu+\frac{1}{2}t^2\sigma^2})=e^\mu E(e^{\frac{1}{2}t^2\sigma^2})$ and then use the result for the MGF of a gamma to calculate the last expectation.

Thanks!

Comment: $E(e^{tX}|Var(x))$ is not what you write.

Comment: Woops, fixing that.

Comment: Hmm.. for a Normal-Gammma distribution, don't you want either $X|\sigma^2 \sim N(0,1/\sigma^2)$ and $\sigma^2 \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(a,b)$ or $X|\sigma^2 \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $1/\sigma^2 \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(a,b)$?

Comment: Wow, that was the issue. A silly error on my part. The MGF for an inverse Gamma does not exist as a real valued function. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a normal gamma distribution as written in the original post. A normal gamma has 
$1/\sigma^2 \sim Gamma(a,b)$. Thus, using the original conditioning argument, you would still have:

$E(e^{tX})=E(E(e^{tX}|\sigma^2))=E(e^{\mu+\frac{1}{2}t^2\sigma^2})=e^\mu E(e^{\frac{1}{2}t^2\sigma^2})$

but $\sigma^2$ now has an inverse gamma distribution. The MGF for inverse gamma distributions does not exist as a real valued function.